# Ansible with_items vs loop

Tags: ansible

What is the difference between using [with_items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html) vs [loops](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) in ansilbe?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Update:** The most recent [Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) lists down the differences as below

> - The with_ keywords rely on Lookup Plugins - even items is a    lookup.
> - The loop keyword is equivalent to with_list, and is the best    choice for simple loops.
> - The loop keyword will not accept a string as    input, see Ensuring list input for loop: query vs. lookup.
> - Generally    speaking, any use of with_* covered in Migrating from with_X to loop    can be updated to use loop.
> - Be careful when changing with_items to    loop, as with_items performed implicit single-level flattening. You    may need to use
>     flatten(1) with loop to match the exact outcome.

---

*Old answer*

As per the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html),

> Before 2.5 Ansible mainly used the with_ keywords to create loops, the loop keyword is basically analogous to with_list.

So basically they are pretty much the same, only the newer version uses `loop` in its syntax. And as of version 2.7.12 both work as expected but using the `loop` keyword is encouraged for future compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

They are different. Be careful when changing with_items to loop, as with_items performed implicit single-level flattening. You may need to use flatten with loop to match the exact outcome. look at the official doc examples.

[Ansible Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#comparing-loop-and-with)