# Migration between with_items to loop

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to migrate some code from with_items to loop.

I have this playbook.yml. Seems they are the same but just changed the with_items to loop

```
- debug:  
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop:   
  - "{{ lookup('pipe','echo -e  \"pro.json\npre.json\ndev.json\"').split('\n') }}"

- debug:  
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
  - "{{ lookup('pipe','echo -e  \"pro.json\npre.json\ndev.json\"').split('\n') }}"
```

This is the output.

```
TASK [loop: debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server] => (item=[u'pro.json', u'pre.json', u'dev.json']) => {
"msg": [
    "pro.json", 
    "pre.json", 
    "dev.json"
]
}

    TASK [with_items : debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Ok: [server] => (item=pro.json) => {
    "msg": "pro.json"
}
ok: [server] => (item=pre.json) => {
    "msg": "pre.json"
}
ok: [server] => (item=dev.json) => {
    "msg": "dev.json"
}
```

As you see loop keeps the output in a kind of chain and with_items split it in three outputs.

I need change the ouput of loop, to look like the with_items. What I want is create a loop that give me a list, depend on the list this loop will be looping.

The with_items result will loop three or as many as the pipe command does but loop only will one

EDIT:

I have tried the with sequence solution for loop and seems this is posible but I cannot change my code to work like.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html?highlight=loop#with-sequence

```
TASK [: with_sequence] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server] => (item=testuser00) => {
    "msg": "testuser00"
}
ok: [server] => (item=testuser02) => {
    "msg": "testuser02"
}
ok: [server] => (item=testuser04) => {
    "msg": "testuser04"
}

TASK [: with_sequence -> loop] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server] => (item=0) => {
    "msg": "testuser00"
}
ok: [server] => (item=2) => {
    "msg": "testuser02"
}
ok: [server] => (item=4) => {
    "msg": "testuser04"
}
```

Comment: Hi...WC to SO! Go through the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  Also what exactly you mean by `I need change the ouput of loop, to look like the with_items. What I want is create a loop that give me a list, depend on the list this loop will be looping` -- the best thing would be explai with example what you want to achieve at last

Comment: Hello, what I want is get the with_items ouput using loop

Comment: I got that but what is the reason of doing this and what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456997/ansible-with-items-vs-loop

Comment: What I want is create a logic with the lookup pipe.

I will check in bash a variable, if the variable match for example with "PRE", it will call the pro.json and pre.json files.

If the variable match with dev, only dev file will be called ( and show as item).
If pro variable shows, I will call the three files.

I know I have to develop a if condition inside the lookup pipe, but for the moment just need to archieve the format with the loop.

Comment: if this is the use case use can/should use `include_vars` with when condition --this is easy to maintain and work. Since you have already accepted the answer. In case your interested let me know I will provide an answer with that logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the list directly and not as a listitem containing the list to loop

```
- debug:  
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('pipe','echo -e  \"pro.json\npre.json\ndev.json\"').split('\n') }}"
```

For more infos see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html